# Doctype is ignoring the percentages

Tags: html, css

I built my page without using Doctype, but I could get the result that I was expecting without it.

I'm trying to list 4 images per line and fill the page even when the user tries to resize the window.

The issue is that I recently added the Doctype and something is not working very well here, the images appeared disorganized.

My page without Doctype

[image]

My page with Doctype

[image]

My JsFiddle is here.

http://jsfiddle.net/fk834aLa/1/

CSS:

```
body{
margin: 0 auto;
}

.photosquare{
height:25%;
width:25%;
float:left;
position:relative;
}

.photosquare img{
height:100%;
width:100%;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="first_page">
<div class="photosquare">
<img src="https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1428278953961-a8bc45e05f72?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&q=75&w=1050" /> 
</div>
<div class="photosquare">
<img src="https://unsplash.imgix.net/photo-1428278953961-a8bc45e05f72?fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=700&q=75&w=1050" /> 
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: All the pics height 700px but one of them is 725 px when fix it problem solved. http://jsfiddle.net/fk834aLa/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentages of height are based on parent elements. 
While your image photosquare did have a percentage height, its parents did not have a defined height.

Check out this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/drecodeam/fk834aLa/3/

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.photosquare {
    height:25%;
    width:25%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.first_page {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.photosquare img {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
```